# «Но всё равно спасибо». Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Недавно написал такое предложение в ответ: **Но всё равно спасибо.**
Скажите, пожалуйста, будут ли внутри предложения присутствовать какие-либо знаки препинания (почему-то мне хочется перед "спасибо" поставить тире)?
И чем выражена грамматическая основа?

Answer (score 3):

*Спасибо* – это частица, которая может выполнять функции вводного слова ("Он, спасибо, не ушёл и не бросил товарища"), дополнения ("Он сказал ей спасибо"), подлежащего ("Его спасибо прозвучало отрывисто и резко"), а может быть предикативом, безличным сказуемым. Вот здесь как раз такой случай: спасибо = хочется поблагодарить.

*Всё равно = всё-таки*, в любом случае – частица, при разборе по членам предложения относится к самостоятельной части речи, значит, грамматическая основа – *всё равно спасибо*, но если Вы произнесёте с фразовым ударением на частицу, она превращается в наречие со значением "обязательно, несмотря ни на что", тогда это будет обстоятельство, а грамматическая основа – предикатив  *спасибо*.

Знаков препинания здесь никаких не надо, но если хочется поставить тире – можно поставить как авторский знак – знак паузы.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробное объяснение!

Comment: *«Всё равно = всё-таки, в любом случае — частица, при разборе по членам предложения относится к самостоятельной части речи, значит, грамматическая основа — всё равно спасибо».* Немного непонятно, как же может «всё равно» входить в грамматическую основу, если это частица, а частица не может быть членом предложения. Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я бы трактовал исходную фразу как "Но все равно (вам) благодарность". Здесь благодарность дополнение, а не сказуемое. Глагола нет, поэтому возможно предпосылки к тире. По аналогии с "Этому - каши, этому - лапшу, а этому - спасибо, которое на хлеб не намажешь."

Comment: Eagle, частицы не являются членами предложений, но могут входить в состав членов предложения. Формообразующие всегда входят, смысловые в зависимости от значения. Иногда говорят "Тесно примыкает к сказуемому", т.е сливается с ним. При разборе их или не подчёркивают вовсе, или подчёркивают вместе со словом, к которому относятся.
Источник: https://anyost.ru/poisonous-mushrooms/vhodit-li-chastica-v-sostav-skazuemogo-kakie-chasticy-mogut.html © anyost.ru

Comment: user190920, вероятно, возможна и такая трактовка, но мне сдаётся, что синтаксис несколько меняется: "говорю спасибо" и просто "спасибо" не одно и то же. А вот если так: Спасибо, что помог. Здесь ведь точно безличное предложение! Предположим, дальше идёт возражение, а далее: Всё равно спасибо. Это ведь ближе? И здесь тоже безличное предложение с грамматической основой "спасибо"